# rxjs 6 type Observable<{}> is not assignable to type Observable<boolean>

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am trying to upgrade rxjs. And I have a typescript error that I don't really understand how to solve it.

```
public IsDebugActivated(): Observable<boolean> {
    const $isDebug = map(isDebug => isDebug === 'true');
    const $consoleDebug = tap(i => {
        if (i) {
            console.log('DEBUG IS ACTIVATED');
        }
    });

    return this.contractCoreService
        .getContractFeatureValue(ContractFeaturesEnum.Features.IsDebugActivated)
        .pipe(
            $isDebug,
            tap(i => {
                if (i) {
                    console.log('DEBUG IS ACTIVATED');
                }
            }))
}
```

I have no typing error. However if I change the last part by

```
 return this.contractCoreService
      .getContractFeatureValue(ContractFeaturesEnum.Features.IsDebugActivated)
      .pipe($isDebug
        , $consoleDebug
  }
```

I have an error on `$consoleDebug` saying

```
type Observable<{}> is not assignable to type Observable<boolean>
```

What's wrong ? Should I cast it? Or is there a better practice ?

For info :

```
getContractFeatureValue(featureName: ContractFeaturesEnum): Observable<any>
```

Comment: `$consoleDebug` is probably getting the type `Observable<{}>` as it can't infer `T`. Try giving it an explicit type

Answer (score 0):

Because your `$consoleDebug` is returning `Observable<{}>` instead of `Observable<boolean>`.

Please try fix it from inside `$consoleDebug`.

Comment: So it is not like .do ?